# problem snapping on the face

Tags: mesh, snapping

I am doing the blender Guru latest Donut tutorial, I am trying to model the icing on top of the donut by proportionally editing it, with the option snap to face activated. The icing mesh keeps on snapping to the inside of the donut rather than the external part.[image]

Comment: hello it doesn't look like the vertices are inside the donut, it's just that the donut faces protrude the icing faces

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your snap is probably set to closest. Set *Snap With* to *Active* instead. (Shift) Select last the vertex that will be the Active Element (becomes white) before moving your selection.

[image]

The way you were doing it, Blender was snapping using the (bounding box) center of all your selected vertices.